# table view data is doubled when we come back to the table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

hii every one

i have a table view n i have say 2 rows in that , using push view controller i am navigating to another page on click of the table row, after navigation when i come back to the table view data is displaying twice,,i.e 2 rows of data will become 4 rows of data with repeated entries

i am using following code to update the view is that causing that problem?

how can i resolve this , can any one help me

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

}
```

Comment: can you post some more codes?

Comment: You are probably using an NSMutableArray instance with an addObject: somewhere.

Comment: show us your cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: reloadData just reloads the data from the datasource you've assigned in numberOfRows:insection:,cellForRowAtIndexPath and such other datasource methods.I 100% agree with Deepak in that you're most probably, even for sure adding objects to the TableView's data source which I assume is NSMutableArray. I'd suggest searching that NSMutableArray in your whole code and see where you addObject(s) to it.If the number of rows double up after you navigate back then it means second level navigation controller is the place to look for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

will not be the cause for increasing the number of rows directly. Pls check the datasource methods for the tableView to see if the array you are using to populate the table view has been changed when you get back to the view. Pls post more code to get better responses